# Resources in Android Library

Tags: android

I have problems with accessing resources in my android library. I have created library project with some resources (com.library) and then I imported module into application project (com.app). So I have Android Studio project with library and application.
When I want to access some library resource (com.library.R.string.label) I get error during compilation

```
package com.library.R does not exist
```

When I want to run some library method from application which contains/uses R.string.label I get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.library.R$string
```

I added library to application gradle file using

```
compile project(':Library')
```

and from IDE perspective looks everything fine and R.java is created with references to resources. I want same usage as I'm using for example android.R.string.cancel or similar libraries in my application project.
Where I'm doing mistake? Thank you for help.
PS: In the future I want to have my library project as aar package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in wrong package name in gradle configuration files (after renaming).

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you add a library to your project all resources will be "copied" to the R-file of your app. So if you want to access a string from your library you don't do something like `getString(com.library.R.string.some_string)` you simply call `getString(R.string.some_string)` instead.

In terms of the library method: Would you mind sharing some code with us? Currently I can't imagine what's going wrong.

Comment: What about using my library as aar? Will everything be "copied" as you mentioned?

Comment: Yep same thing goes for aar. Think of aar as jar-files (though there somewhat different).